# Can I power two Raspberry Pis from one Powered Hub?

Tags: raspbian, usb-power, power

I have this hub: [Mod My Pi 4 Port USB Hub](https://www.modmypi.com/New-Link-4-Port-USB-Hub-%28USB-2.0-with-Mains-Adaptor%29), which is recommended for use with the Raspberry.

I have two Raspberries but one Hub. My Question is:

**Can I power both Raspberries at the same time, without having any problem?**

If so, can I also have a Wifi Dongle connected on the one Raspberry? *(I will probably share its connection with the other one through Ethernet...)*

I ask this question because when I tried to power both Raspberries (connected via Ethernet to my Router), the one Raspberry didn't Boot (stuck on Rebooting), and the other one didn't connect to the Internet.

**Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: You should check the voltage while they are plugged in:  http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#How_Can_I_tell_if_the_power_supply_is_inadequate.3F You can find a cheap multimeter at any hardware store for ~$10.

Comment: I have a Multimeter already... I am going to check it!

Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible depending on if you are running anything else off the USB of the PI ethernet is included.  Generally hubs will only deliver 500ma per port and thats at the bottom of what the pi will want.  So if you can find a powered hub that delivers 700ma per port then you will be fine as long as it is a 2amp hub.  Adafruit.com sells one that I have had success with.  Wifi dongles should be run off the hub as well if you are going to power the pi off the hub.  The symptom is typical of power starvation for the pi.

Comment: Thanks for the Anwser! Well, I believe I have to power one Pi at a time with the hub I have... (I don't want to spend more money on the Raspberry Stuff!)